# Changing ServiceHost EndPoint Address at Runtime C#

Tags: c#, wcf, service, servicehost

I'm busy writing a file server/client tool that basically uses a hosted Service to send and receive data to and from the server. Since this solution will be used by many different people, its not really advisable to have them go and edit the App.Config file for their setup. What I would like to do is change this at runtime so that the user(s) have full control over the settings to use. So, this is my App.Config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="FI.ProBooks.FileSystem.FileRepositoryService">
                <endpoint name="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                    address="net.tcp://localhost:5000"
                    contract="FI.ProBooks.FileSystem.IFileRepositoryService"
                    bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="customTcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="20480000" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

What I would like to do is to change only the address (in this example, net.tcp://localhost:5000) when the application is executed. So I must be able to read the current value and display that to the user, and then take their input and save it back into that field.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the service instance providing a configuration name and endpoint. So you can use;

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
var client= new MyServiceClient(endpointConfigurationName,endpoint )
```

look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee637899.aspx) article.

Comment: The question was regarding a ServiceHost and not a client

Answer (score 1):

The test below may help you.  Essentially the steps are

- Instantiate an instance of the host that reads the configuration from the .config file;
- Create a new instance of `EndpointAddress` using the same configuration as the old one, but changing the uri and assign it to the `Address` property of your `ServiceEndpoint`.

  ```
  [TestMethod]
  public void ChangeEndpointAddressAtRuntime()
  {
      var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileRepositoryService));

      var serviceEndpoint = host.Description.Endpoints.First(e => e.Contract.ContractType == typeof (IFileRepositoryService));
      var oldAddress = serviceEndpoint.Address;
      Console.WriteLine("Curent Address: {0}", oldAddress.Uri);

      var newAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:5001";
      Console.WriteLine("New Address: {0}", newAddress);
      serviceEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(newAddress), oldAddress.Identity, oldAddress.Headers);
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => host.Open());

      var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFileRepositoryService>(new NetTcpBinding("customTcpBinding"), new EndpointAddress(newAddress));
      var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

      channel.Method();

      (channel as ICommunicationObject).Close();


      channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFileRepositoryService>(new NetTcpBinding("customTcpBinding"), oldAddress);
      channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

      bool failedWithOldAddress = false;
      try
      {
          channel.Method();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          failedWithOldAddress = true;
      }

      (channel as ICommunicationObject).Close();

      Assert.IsTrue(failedWithOldAddress);  
  }
  ```

Comment: don't like all the var but your answer was helpful overall, thanks.